# User that *never* shows work

Tags: discussion

I have spotted a user with reputation 600 that doesn't show work for any question. All of them are SOPs and basically say "thanks in advance" as his work...

I know SOPs are allowed but what about a user that *strictly* posts SOPs, showing no work whatsoever? Isn't this discouraged?

P.S. His answer-to-question ratio is 1:13.

Comment: Sorry, what does "SOP" mean again?

Comment: Statement-of-problem with no work

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with SOP's?
An explanation how an OP tried to solve a problem is often irrelevant to the solution(s).
Moreover, it often obscures the question.

Comment: @MakotoKato "An explanation how an OP tried to solve a problem is often irrelevant to the solution(s)." One can (and many people do) think that the exact opposite conclusion holds. "Moreover, it often obscures the question." One can (and many people do) think that the exact opposite conclusion holds.

Comment: @Makoto: Although correct, it shows no effort on their part, and furthermore, discourages self-learning.

Comment: @Did There are usually several(or many) different solutions of a problem.
Asking about a particular solution of a problem is not usually a good idea.
Demanding an OP to explain how she tried to solve the problem can often be counterproductive because it tends to make us concentrate on her way of thinking.

Comment: @DonLarynx If you want to encourage self-learning, how about ignoring his question?

Comment: @Makoto: I don't see how that solves his problem....Please be constructive.

Comment: You just don't like to give away an answer for free, do you?
In that case, you don't have to answer at all.

Comment: Why? I think it's very constructive not to give an answer and make her think about the problem herself.

Comment: @MakotoKato "Demanding an OP to explain how she tried to solve the problem can often be counterproductive because it tends to make us concentrate on her way of thinking." Sorry but I fully disagree. Would you have any empirical evidence in support of this assertion? Ditto for the ones in your previous comment.

Comment: The empirical evidence is that in the large majority of cases, there is no visible reference to the OP's "work and effort" in the answer.  This is not accidental, because continuing from the OP's work (lacking, as it so often does, a usable grasp of the problem or the ideas needed in the solution) tends to be either not possible, or makes a clean exposition more difficult, when writing an answer. I suggest to anyone interested to gather some data on what has actually been the result of the "work and effort" movement and whether it is pushing in the good or bad directions.

Comment: By design, this site allows people to get answers to questions about the Harry Potter books. But somehow, we've managed to avoid having MSE flooded with those.

Comment: The most obvious way that SOPs "obscure the question" is that people believe that the P *is* the question.

Comment: A question is (pretty much by definition on an SE-style web site) whatever the answerers decide to make of it.  Third party kibitzer opinion is much less useful, particularly when presented in the form of vague rhetorical insinuations and self-assigned personal control over what is and is not "a real question" or "the question".

Comment: @Hurkyl Do not get the wrong idea that it is moderation and flags what stops this site from being flooded with Harry Potter questions. By design, you make a mathematics question-answer site and the users you will get is students that need answers to their questions and a handful of professionals taking a break from their research/work.

Comment: All in all, the fight against problem set questions is not even a noble one. It is just a fake sense of what is right. The only one favored by such a fight is the despotic teacher that administered the problem set in some god forsaken bad university/high school/primary school. No online impersonal command to show some work is going to teach any student the value of working a bit on a problem before seeing the solution. It only makes it slower for them to see those solutions. Seeing solutions is very important for the student.

Comment: An important component of what a homework is, is that the student may find help from others to solve the problems, see the solutions somewhere. Any teacher expecting a homework to be treated as an individual examination is doing his/her work wrong, and misusing the different forms of evaluation.

Comment: I just want to remind all of you that have studied mathematics how much have you learned from your own solutions or from seeing other's solutions. For those of you that have trained for math competitions. How much seeing solutions and types of problems plays a role in your training. For those of you that do research, how much of your research is to read other's papers and to imitate(!) their proofs in new contexts. For those of you that teach, how many exams you have seen that students answers are scattered computations that contain the final answer. Yes, that comes from students ...

Comment: that haven't seen well written solutions.

Comment: > *By design, this site allows people to get answers to questions about the Harry Potter books*. <-- Sure, as long as you deliberate ignore the name of the website, the huge title Mathematics on the front page, the SciFi and movies SE sites, and the presumed opinion of the other 99.99% of users that Harry Potter questions are obviously not mathematics.  //  > *But somehow, we've managed to avoid having MSE flooded with those.* < -- Sure, if there were a lot of people trying to post HP questions on MSE, that might be a relevant point and not a bizarre but recurring digression.  @Hurkyl

Comment: @zyx: He argues homework is like "an exam" if we adopt the attitude I have. **How so?** It encourages the student to think about it. I would like to hear some thoughts on the question the student has posed.

Comment: @ABC: Please start using more constructive language. I have nuked my last two statements.

Comment: Homework is treated as evaluation by many of us,regardless of any attitude. We give homework in class and we sometimes mark it and use it to grade students. What is wrong is to expect that homework is an individual work (let me be clear, homework in 'pure mathematics', an essay in philosophy, or even some projects in applied mathematics may have different nature). It is this misconception, or malpractice, what makes some people here think that giving answers to homework is a bad thing, that is somehow going to spoil the educational process.

Comment: A hint is  much more constructive way of stimulating individual work. when you ask "did you try something?" you can always reply "I don't even know how to begin". It is a waste of time. Like small talk. There is a reason in Internet, often the "hello-hello", "Dear ...", etc. doesn't have a place and even disappears. Giving a hint, comparing the problem to other problems, pointing to references, can serve the same purpose of stimulating individual work, and at the same time put in motion the process that makes the solution appear written in this website (which eventually will always appear).

Comment: @ABC: If they do not know how to begin, they should be Googling information. There are PSQs, and there are questions that show effort and are not unclear. Which do you prefer?

Comment: I do prefer a clearly stated problem-only question (short, readable, unambiguous) over something where 80 percent of the question consists of OP ramblings added to the same mathematics problem.   If the OP has anything that makes the *mathematics* in the question objectively easier to understand, appreciate or solve, such as graphs and data tables, proofs of lemmas and special cases, links and references about the problem or related ones -- that is excellent, and I do want to see that, but it is a **rare case** that this is the "effort".

Comment: @DonLarynx Next time you are trying to solve a problem, which main part is an equation, a formula, try googling that. It is not so easy to Google a formula. The other day I was trying to remember from what IMO was certain Diophantine equation and it wasn't so easy. It is simply animosity towards the people trying to learn to send them elsewhere to learn mathematics. You can imagine young kids, from places of the earth without much internet access, or books, trying to learn stuff that are advanced for them. It is evil to mistreat them or make them waste internet time like that.

Comment: And that exists, because I once used this very website under those circumstances. I don't remember being mistreated. But imagine having a connection ten times slower than your cellphone, not frequent access to a computer, you post a question, and the next week when you manage to connect again, you only see: "what did you try?" or "show some work". Uff.

Comment: It's bad enough to make people waste internet time reading useless junk in the questions! And worse to try to enforce the inclusion of the junk as an obedience ritual.  @ABC

Comment: That's what I think.

Comment: Okay, I'll start asking PSQs only. Let's see how that works out. :)

Comment: @ABC: On a serious comment, one should introduce oneself as someone with bad circumstances, then. Otherwise, we don't know who you are - someone in bad circumstances or someone with bad habits.

Comment: The user profile is for introductions and personal information (the person has background X, is at institution Y, is taking class Z, has internet difficulties, or whatever else).  All that should be kept out of the questions or linked from the top comment under the question.   @DonLarynx

Comment: @ABC: zyx has answered our dilemma.

Comment: A long time ago I was a TA who usually taught problem solving for first year calculus. I would have a student who could not answer some problem tell what they did. So long as they made no mathematical errors I let them continue. When they got to the point where they gave up I would ask for another student to complete the problem. I would continue my job as a stenographer. At the end of the process we would have an answer. We would see what was necessary and what could be eliminated. The process was slow enough that virtually every one in the class was able to understand how to solve the ...

Comment: ... problem. The first person would get a solution based on their work. The other students might see a way of doing the problem that differed from theirs. Also the students in my sections did far better on common exams than the students in other sections.

Comment: I agree with everything @zyx has said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is definitely discouraged. When we (the moderators) notice that a user repeatedly posts PSQs (Problem Statement Questions, which I assume are the same as SOPs) and shows no effort to improve them, we generally contact the user privately about their behavior. If they continue, it becomes grounds for a suspension.

If you think a user has been asking a lot of low-quality questions, the best practice is probably to flag one of them as "very low quality", which will get the moderators' attention.

Comment: I have downvoted 4 of his questions and will flag all of them. However, I am hoping he is let off with a warning.

Comment: What's wrong with SOPs?

Comment: @MakotoKato Complete acceptance of homework-level PSQs turns Math.SE into a homework-answering/take-home-test-cheating service in the eyes of the rest of the internet. As we want Math.SE to maintain some reputation in the eyes of academia, we don't want users to *only* use Math.SE for these lower-level PSQs. In short--there's nothing wrong with *a* PSQ, but an overabundance is harmful to the site's reputation.  But that's the topic of a different meta thread.

Comment: @DonLarynx I would recommend against downvoting a whole slate of a user's questions. For one thing, the downvotes are likely to be automatically reversed.

Comment: @anorton, I think there is more evidence that cultivated hostility to problem-only questions turns MSE and its meta into an adult kindergarten, with users pointing fingers at each other and seeking to limit others' conduct as a sport unto itself, than indications that it makes MSE questions better or improves MSE's reputation.

Comment: I think SOPs should be limited, at the very least.

Comment: @anorton You can't forbid homework questions in this site.
Better get over it.

Comment: @Makoto Just because something is unattainable doesn't mean it isn't worth fighting for.

Comment: @anorton It's easy to win over them. If you don't want to give away an answer, you can ignore them.

Comment: Do you really suspend people who don't elaborate on their questions? Assuming the questions themselves are interesting and not just copied homework, I find that objectionable.

Comment: @Potato If the questions are interesting and not just copied from homework? Of course not. I'm only addressing boring homework questions with no work shown.

Comment: There has been a longstanding preference by users and moderators (and, I think, Stackexchange as expressed on their blogs and MSO) that outside of very well defined categories -- spam, offensive, illegal, migration, blatantly off-topic -- moderators not make subjective content judgements on users' postings, such as being correct, or boring, or homework.  The only situation I can think of where such a thing would **not** be objectionable is a software-generated user suspension queue with mods manually rescuing some of those.  Is that what it is? @AlexBecker

Comment: @zyx That's not quite the case - SE has been very clear about its "optimized for pearls, not sand" policy, to quote. But what I'm talking about is not deleting questions (which is something we do with great reserve, and only in the cases you cite) but rather contacting and possibly suspending users. Indeed, "continuous low quality contributions over time" is one of the default templates for mod messages, and one of the most frequently used.

Comment: @AlexBecker, I was talking only about suspensions.  The question is how potential suspend-ees (or the subset on which the boring/homework decisions are being made about their postings) get into the pool on which moderators make decisions, and whether the threshold for that is entirely under software control based on statistics such as flags, downvotes, close votes, deletions -- or if one flag from one user can trigger a review of the user.

Comment: @zyx There is really no such thing as "triggering a review"; if a user comes to the moderators attention, we look into the user's history and consider action. Lots of flags is one way this can happen, and certain things like lots of closed question will result in automatic system flags, but there's no fixed threshold. I've definitely looked into users not as a result of flags but from seeing their posts myself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I don't know what you considered "not quite the case": users have been clear about it in the meta, and moderators (such as Willie recently, and several others before that) have periodically answered on meta that it is not their job to make correctness judgements.  As far as  SE is concerned, the "optimize for pearls" was a description of what all the voting and flagging and reputation tools distributed to *users* is supposed to accomplish, as well as some design decisions by SE.  Lots of high effort users could be suspended for "boring" posts if it's more than that.

Comment: The "optimize for pearls" SE blog post, by the way, does not include the word *moderators*, and was about user capabilities and SE design ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ ).  A repeating theme in the SE blogs tagged [moderators] is '...moderators are the “human exception handlers” on Stack Overflow, elected to deal with those rare situations the normal community moderation can’t handle...' and similar excerpts from http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/ .   So I don't see what you think was wrong in the initial comment. @AlexBecker

Comment: @anorton, the trouble is that the fight, even if (in the fighters' perception) is for a good reason, is causing collateral damage such as: making questions "too localized", longer, less readable, and filled with on-demand Junk Context; shutting down interesting questions that don't have those problems for purely stylistic reasons; and creating the adult kindergarten atmosphere described above, which surely does *not* help MSE's quality or outside reputation.  Better to focus on objectively useful and usable characteristics of questions (**sources!**), and not the nebulous "context and effort".

Comment: @zyx Amen.  $\textbf{}$

Comment: @zyx yeah... that is the conclusion to which I am slowly arriving...  as much as I'd like it to be different.

Comment: @zyx: The ideal *objectively useful and usable* characteristic of a question is, e.g., what mathematical concepts and theorems one seeks to understand. The point of 'context and effort' is to better help those who don't know what they don't know. I am also increasingly of the opinion that it's not so great for MSE, but I take away the exact opposite conclusion: *these questions don't belong on MSE at all*.

Comment: Clarity about the target of the question is obviously high on the list of what is desired, but hard to define precisely. Tags, titles, correctly used mathematical language, proofs of special cases and lemmas, graphs, data tables, relevant formulas, (sources...) -- are all indicators.  I don't know which questions you think don't belong at all on MSE or why, but here are two answers: they could belong on an additional site (e.g., a math-help.SE); and that garbage collection is for SE to automate, but improving user ability to isolate what one *does* want to read is more urgent. @Hurkyl

Comment: There is also this earlier comment about usable objective characteristics: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/user-that-never-shows-work#comment47332_12121 . And some related comments about the importance of machine readable metadata: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12012/if-i-vote-to-close-a-question-because-of-no-effort-shown-is-the-op-given-a-reas/12013#comment46870_12013 .   @Hurkyl

Comment: @AlexBecker "I would recommend against downvoting a whole slate of a user's questions. For one thing, the downvotes are likely to be automatically reversed." I have flagged against user Wicht and no action is being taken. So...should I start doing this too in sight that my actions won't be re-primanded?

Comment: @DonLarynx You should never serially downvote a user. It's worth noting that just because you haven't *seen* any action taken by the moderators, doesn't mean none has been taken. Our standard approach is to contact users privately, which is not visible to other users.